# Не показывается скролл прокрутки на телефоне?

Tags: html, css, css3

Всем привет

У меня у блока есть `overflow: scroll;` и на десктопе виден скролл сбоку, а на телефоне его нет, там просто пустое место. Что делать?

Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На телефоне скролл появляется при скролировании. Также наличие и вид скролла зависит от ОС и ее настроек. К примеру, на macOS по умолчанию также не видно скролл, однако его можно настроить. Однако отсутствие видимого скролла вовсе не значит, что блок нельзя скролировать.

Если скролл вашем дизайне является обязательным требованием, то его можно кастомизировать с помощью JS-библиотек, или же CSS. Кастомизация на CSS поддерживается пока-что только браузерами на базе движка webkit. Ниже привожу пример кастомизации:

```
        ::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 5px;
        }
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background: #f2f3f7;
            border-radius: 2px;
        }
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
            background: #fff;
        }
```

Для решения на JS советую прочитать статью https://habrahabr.ru/company/2gis/blog/169359/